# Getting values from a keyvaluepair in xaml

Tags: xaml

I have a GridView that's bound to a Dictionary:

```
        <GridView x:Uid="SearchInputRecentSearches"
                  x:Name="SearchInputRecentSearches"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding RecentSearches}"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Style="{StaticResource RecentSearchGrid}">
```

Inside of this GridView, in the ItemTemplate, I want to show the Key or Value:

```
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource RecentSearchesItemStackPanel}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                    <Button Width="31"
                            Height="31"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.ExecuteDeleteSearch, ElementName=SearchInputRecentSearches}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Key}"
                            Template="{StaticResource DeleteButton}"/>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource RecentSearchStyle}"
                               Text="{Binding Value}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

However, nothing displays for either Key or Value when I run this. I've tried referring to Path=Key and Path=Value inside of the binding, but this doesn't work, either. I'm currently using a ValueConverter to get the key or value out, but this seems a little unnecessary and I was hoping someone could point out what I was doing wrong!

Comment: Have you set the DataContext on the parent control? Are you getting any binding errors in the output?

Comment: Thanks Mike - yes, DataContext is set to a ViewModel (we're using Prism), and all other bindings work. In fact, that binding will work - if I change the first `<TextBlock>` to be:

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>`

I will see the whole KeyValue pair, as the ToString method looks to have been called. So the data's there, it's just not straightforward to get at it.